# if formula not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

entire formula which is not working properly:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(K28,AD:AF,3,FALSE)="offset","offset",IF(L28="",VLOOKUP(N28,AM:AN,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(L28,AJ:AN,5,FALSE)))
```

This part of the formula by itself, works properly and returns what I need:

```
=IF(L28="",VLOOKUP(N28,AM:AN,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(L28,AJ:AN,5,FALSE))
```

However once combined with the rest of the formula, this part of it doesn't work:

```
VLOOKUP(N28,AM:AN,2,FALSE).
```

Every other part of the formula works though.
Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: For future reference, *'it doesn't work'* is not a valid error description. Do you receive a worksheet error code and if so, what is it? Sounds like an `#N/A` issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

If K28 is found in AD:AD, then that formula should work regardless of whether *offset* is found in AF:AF or not. However, if K28 is **not** found in AD:AD, then that first VLOOKUP returns an #N/A error and everything stops there. You need error control on at least that first VLOOKUP.

```
=IF(iferror(VLOOKUP(K28,AD:AF,3,FALSE), "err")="offset", "offset", IF(L28="", VLOOKUP(N28,AM:AN,2,FALSE), VLOOKUP(L28,AJ:AN,5,FALSE)))

'alternate
=iferror(VLOOKUP(K28,AD:AF,3,FALSE), IF(L28="", VLOOKUP(N28,AM:AN,2,FALSE), VLOOKUP(L28,AJ:AN,5,FALSE)))
```

I always error control each and every VLOOKUP I implement but that is a personal choice. You can add a couple more IFERROR wrappers if you wish.